# $K(\Gamma)$ is an algebraic extension.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $L/K$ be a field extension and $\Gamma \subset L$ such that for all $\alpha \in \Gamma$, $\alpha$ is algebraic over K. Show that $K(\Gamma)/K$ is algebraic.

My attempt:

Since every element of $\Gamma$ is algebraic over $L$, we have that $K(\Gamma)=K[\Gamma]$.
Now, given $a \in K(\Gamma)$ we need to find a polinomyal $f \in K[x]- \lbrace 0 \rbrace $, such that $f(a)=0$.
Since $K(\Gamma)=K[\Gamma]$, $a$ is a polynomial, let's say $h$, which is evaluated on the elements of $\Gamma$.

From here I don't know how to build the polynomial $ f $. Any hint?

Comment: Hint: you don't have to build such polynomial. Rather, you can argue that $a=g(a_1,\ldots ,a_k)$ for a polynomial $g$ and $a_i \in \Gamma$. Now consider $K(a_1,\ldots ,a_k)$.

Comment: A doubt. We don't know if $\Gamma$ is finite or infinite ... why can I choose $g$ such that it has $k$ indeterminate? @mathmath

Comment: What is the definition of $K(\Gamma)$?

Comment: You're right, in this case $K(\Gamma)=K[\Gamma]= \lbrace f(u_1,...,u_n) : f \in K[x_1,...,x_n], u_1,...,u_n \in \Gamma \rbrace $. I'm going to try with your hint, thanks @mathmath

Comment: $K(a_1,\ldots ,a_k)$ is an at most $d=\prod_j d_j$ dimensional $K$-vector space, where $d_j$ is the degree of $a_j$'s minimal polynomial, and thus $K(a)$ is a finite $\le d$ dimensional $K$-vector space which means that $a^d$ is a $K$-linear combination of $a^m,0\le m\le d-1$ ie. $a$ is algebraic.

Comment: Clearly $K(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n) \subset K(\Gamma)$. But $K(\Gamma)$ is the minimum field that contains $K$ and $\Gamma$, in particular, it is the minimum field that contains $K$ and each $\alpha_i$, hence $K(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)=K(\Gamma)$ and as $K(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_{n-1})(\alpha_n)=K(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$ and $\alpha_n$ is algebraic over $K$, we have that $K(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)/K$ is algebraic, i.e. $K(\Gamma)/K$ is algebraic.
Is this correct? @mathmath

Comment: @RicardoCalderón So, you can assume that $\Gamma$ is finite? It seems you're doing that in your approach.

Comment: No, I'm not assuming that @Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof.

Let $E=K(\Gamma)$ then $\Gamma \subset E$. Let $F= \lbrace \alpha \in E : \alpha$ is algebraic over $K \rbrace$.

We have that $F$ is a fiel such that $K\subset F \subset E$. Therefore, $E=K(\Gamma) \subset K(F)=KF=F$, hence $F=E$, i.e. $K(\Gamma)/K$ is algebraic.